# Android - Display Image Caption Below Images in Gridview

Tags: android

I am utilizing a version of the "Grid View" example from the Android Developers site:

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html

And I would like to display a small text caption below each of the images.

Can someone please give an example of how this might be accomplished (i.e. what needs to be edited)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Instead of an `ImageAdapter` returning `ImageViews` from `getView()`, you would need a `TylerAdapter` returning a `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout` for each cell, with the layout containing your `ImageView` and `TextView` caption.

[Here is a free excerpt](http://commonsware.com/Android/excerpt.pdf) from one of books that illustrates stuff like this, albeit in the context of a `ListView` instead of a `GridView`. Those are both `AdapterViews`, and so the techniques are nearly identical.

Comment: Thank you, however I am afraid I am still having trouble.. The example you gave me makes sense, but they use "SetListAdapter" which allows you to pass a layout to it, but since I am trying to use gridview, I cannot seem to figure out how to accomplish the same. 

Are you able to illustrate it better for me by any chance?